# Why is the state in mapStateToProps undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

reducers/counter.js

```
export type counterStateType = {
  +ctr: number,
  +counter: boolean
};

type actionType = {
  +type: string,
  +value: any
};    

export default function counter(state: counterStateType = { ctr: 0, counter: true}, action: actionType) {
  console.log("Reducer called with");
  console.log(state);//has valid value ie { ctr: 0, counter: true}  
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
      state.counter = !state.counter;
      return state;
    case UPDATE:
      state.ctr = action.value;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[image]

counterPage.js

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("mapStateToProps called with");
  console.log(state.counter);

  return {
    ctr: state.counter.ctr,//<= undefined
    counter: state.counter.counter
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(CounterActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

[image]

PS: The above is on router LOCATION_CHANGE

Comment: check what is state.counter

Comment: it was evedent from printing state  itself, but now updated the question for your convinience.

Comment: Your counter was originally true, now it is false in mapStateToProps.  Can you show the code updating the counter object and the reducer updating it.

Comment: solved the issue, the problem was in reducer, here I have omited the state updation swich case of the reducer. but the problem was there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in reducer, I had forgotten about immutablity of redux states. modifying,

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
      state.counter = !state.counter;
      return state;
    case UPDATE:
      state.ctr = action.value;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

to

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
      return {ctr: state.ctr, counter: !state.counter};
    case UPDATE:
      return {ctr: action.value, counter: state.counter};
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

solved it.